# using scrapy creating a spider and unable to store data to csv

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I'm pretty new to scrapy, here I created a spider using the amazon URL unable to get the output to the csv.

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy

class AmazonMotoMobilesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "amazon"
start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.in/Samsung-Mobiles/b/ref=amb_link_47?ie=UTF8&node=4363159031&pf_rd_m=A1VBAL9TL5WCBF&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-leftnav&pf_rd_r=NGA52N9RAWY1W103MPZX&pf_rd_r=NGA52N9RAWY1W103MPZX&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1ce3e975-c6e8-479a-8485-2e490b9f58a9&pf_rd_p=1ce3e975-c6e8-479a-8485-2e490b9f58a9&pf_rd_i=1389401031',]
def parse(self,response):
    product_name = response.xpath('//h2[contains(@class,"a-size-base s-inline  s-access-title  a-text-normal")]/text()').extract()
    product_price = response.xpath('//span[contains(@class,"a-size-base a-color-price s-price a-text-bold")]/text()').extract()
    yield {'product_name'product_name,'product_price': product_price}
```

My shell is showing this result:

> len(response.xpath('//h2[contains(@class,"a-size-base s-inline  s-access-tit
>   le  a-text-normal")]/text()'))
>   24

do I need to change any settings ?

Comment: How you ran the scraper? Do you get any error in logs? Also check of the typo @Arun mentioned is what is causing the issue

Comment: I run my spider like this : scrapy crawl  spidername  , No errors my shell is giving me the count of results but not outputting to csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate results in CSV you need to run the crawler with a output option

```
scrapy crawl -o results.csv spidername
```

Only when you activate a output the results are sent to the file. Else they will processed by your piplelines. If you are not saving them anywhere through pipeline then they will be just on terminal's console logs

Comment: the code is showing me   File "C:\Users\imp\first_scrapy\first_scrapy\spiders\Amazon_MotoMobiles.py", l
ine 9
    yield {'ProductName' : product_name,'Price': product_price}
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: Post your complete file in http://pastebin.com/ and share a link for investigation

Comment: it worked ...thank you so much @tarun lalwani ................what is the problem with my lines of code

Comment: Python is indentation dependent, you can have random # of spaces like other language. You need to keep space for each level to same.

Comment: yes,u were right i used tabs instead of # of spaces

Comment: i had generated my CSV with 4 columns and 24 rows but the results are being iterated in each row alternatively(leaving a blank row).here is the link for my code https://pastebin.com/SueECia1

Comment: Are you using windows?

Comment: Look at this thread then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908465/cant-get-rid-of-blank-rows-in-csv-output/45909282#45909282

Comment: great..it worked , i added exporters.py. but as i sad each col and row  is repeatedly showing all 24 results. if i am not clear please view the CSV result of my code https://pastebin.com/xM69X1BD

Comment: This is an issue with your xpath. You need to start all your xpath with `.//` instead of `//`. So that you search only in current element

Comment: please help me out with this @TARUN LALWANI. Csv is generated using scrapy for multiple pages. but the CSV rows are being iterated . y is it so ? here is my code pastebin.com/U790bFyW

Comment: @Zarinaveeru, this is a separate issue from your existing question, please post a new question. Also on SO once a problem is solved, the answer which solved your issue should be accepted as the answer

Comment: i had accepted the answer . and here is my next question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46768361/unable-to-generate-csv-for-next-pages-using-scrapy

Answer (score 0):

I think Its because your yield has some syntax errors in the dictionary.

Change this

```
yield {'product_name'product_name,'product_price': product_price}
```

to

```
yield {'product_name':product_name,'product_price': product_price}
```

Comment: I corrected my code ... then too the console is throwing me error

Comment: yield {'ProductName' : product_name,'Price': product_price}
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level                                              Here is my edited code           
          
 
            yield {'ProductName' : product_name,'Price': product_price}