# Unable to generate csv for next pages using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am newbie to python and scrapy

Here is my code to get all the productname,price,image,title from all the next pages

```
import scrapy      
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):    
name = "testdoc1"    
start_urls = ["https://www.amazon.in/s/ref=amb_link_46?ie=UTF8&bbn=1389432031&rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A976419031%2Cn%3A%21976420031%2Cn%3A1389401031%2Cn%3A1389432031%2Cp_89%3AApple&pf_rd_m=A1VBAL9TL5WCBF&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-leftnav&pf_rd_r=CYS25V3W021MSYPQ32FB&pf_rd_r=CYS25V3W021MSYPQ32FB&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1ce3e975-c6e8-479a-8485-2e490b9f58a9&pf_rd_p=1ce3e975-c6e8-479a-8485-2e490b9f58a9&pf_rd_i=1389401031"]

def parse(self, response):
    for post_link in response.xpath('//a/@href').extract():
        link = response.urljoin(post_link)
        yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_post)

    # Checks if the main page has a link to next page if True keep parsing.
    next_page = response.xpath('(//a[@class="pagnNext"])[1]/@href').extract_first()
    if next_page:
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)

def parse_post(self, response):
    # Scrape name,price,image, link from product.
    for post in response.xpath('//li[contains(@class,"s-result-item  celwidget")]'):
        item = dict()
        item['Name'] = post.xpath('.//h2[contains(@class,"a-size-base s-inline  s-access-title  a-text-normal")]/text()').extract()
        item['Price'] = post.xpath('.//span[contains(@class,"a-size-base a-color-price s-price a-text-bold")]/text()').extract()
        item['Image'] = post.xpath('.//img[contains(@class,"s-access-image cfMarker")]/@src').extract()
        item['Link'] = post.sel.xpath('.//a[contains(@class,"a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal")]/@href').extract()
        yield item

    # If the products page has a link to next page keep parsing.
    next_page = response.xpath('(//a[@class="pagnNext"])[1]/@href').extract_first()
    if next_page:
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse_post)
```

My crawl is not giving any errors but my CSV is empty
    `

Comment: what's your question ?

Comment: Please be specific about your problem, what you did to solve it and where you need help.

Comment: You have wrong xpaths.

Comment: yes i corrected my xpath "post.sel.xpath(" but the csv generated is giving iterated results . here is my code  https://pastebin.com/U790bFyW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is below line

```
yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

The URL is coming as relative URL. So you should use

```
yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

This will automatically resolve relative URLs

**Edit-1**

Just realized that your are browsing individual pages and you just need to extract the data from the results page. So your `parse_post` function is not needed at all. Below is how you need to do it

```
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "testdoc1"
    allowed_domains = ['amazon.in']
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.amazon.in/s/ref=amb_link_46?ie=UTF8&bbn=1389432031&rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A976419031%2Cn%3A%21976420031%2Cn%3A1389401031%2Cn%3A1389432031%2Cp_89%3AApple&pf_rd_m=A1VBAL9TL5WCBF&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-leftnav&pf_rd_r=CYS25V3W021MSYPQ32FB&pf_rd_r=CYS25V3W021MSYPQ32FB&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1ce3e975-c6e8-479a-8485-2e490b9f58a9&pf_rd_p=1ce3e975-c6e8-479a-8485-2e490b9f58a9&pf_rd_i=1389401031"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for post in response.css('li.s-result-item'):
            item = dict()
            item['Name'] = post.xpath(
                './/h2[contains(@class,"a-size-base s-inline  s-access-title  a-text-normal")]/text()').extract()
            item['Price'] = post.xpath(
                './/span[contains(@class,"a-size-base a-color-price s-price a-text-bold")]/text()').extract()
            item['Image'] = post.xpath('.//img[contains(@class,"s-access-image cfMarker")]/@src').extract()
            item['Link'] = post.xpath(
                './/a[contains(@class,"a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal")]/@href').extract()
            yield item


        # Checks if the main page has a link to next page if True keep parsing.
        next_page = response.xpath('(//a[@class="pagnNext"])[1]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Sir, I changed my code . But CSV is not generating the exact results from all the next pages . why is it so ?