# Scrapy csv export without blank rows

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I have the following scrapy code:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class AliSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "alibot"
    allowed_domains = ["alibaba.com"]
    start_urls = {
        'http://www.alibaba.com/catalog/power-banks_cid100009648',
    }

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('product-detail')), callback = 'parse_page', follow = True),)

    def parse_page(self,response):
        yield {'URL':response.url}
```

When i run `scrapy crawl alibot -o data.csv`it saves urls in a csv file.
I don't want blank rows between two values. I could remove it with excel but it becomes tedious when it's large data. I don't want blank rows between two values because other scrapy code imports this csv file and extracts data from each link. If it finds a blank row, it stops there, which i don't want. How do i do that? Thanks.

data.csv::

```
URL

http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/mini-portable-qi-wireless-phone-charging_60793204715.html?s=p

http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/New-Portable-Power-Bank-4000mah-Slim_60445623561.html

http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/100W-40800mah-portable-power-bank-station_60696475188.html

http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Portable-universal-solar-charger-solar-power_60230498369.html

http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/HE-M19-Hand-Warmer-Power-Bank_60694294192.html
```

Comment: Did you check if it's not an issue with dos/unix linebreak?

Comment: and how do i check that

Comment: Use an editor which can read plain files and shows the special characters

Comment: Have you tried `response.url.strip()` to make sure there isn't something at the end of the data?

Answer (score 2):

ok, this posts helped me out: [Can't get rid of blank rows in csv output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908465/cant-get-rid-of-blank-rows-in-csv-output).
Make these changes in setting.py file.

```
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'csv': 'your_project_name.exporters.FixLineCsvItemExporter',
}
```

Add paste the exporters.py file inside the spider folder where there is `__init__` file. and bam, the output file doesnot contain blank rows.